# Get the count value in android app from webservice

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services, soap

If I run my application, the count value is displayed on my tomcat-apache, but it is not displayed on my Android emulator. Why is this error is occurring here? Where should I change my code:
dis is my webservice code:

```
       PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date = CURDATE()");

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

       while(result.next()){

   int count=0;
   count++;
  System.out.println(count);
   }
   }

   catch(Exception exc){
     System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
      }

    return customerInfo;
    }
```

This is my android code:

```
       HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        String str = s.toString();
        String resultArr[] = str.split("&");//Result string will split & store in an array

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        for(int i = 0; i<resultArr.length;i++){
        tv.append(resultArr[i]+"\n\n");
       }
        setContentView(tv);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the count outside of your loop (as well as the print statement):

```
int count=0;    
while(result.next()){
   count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: now also the count value is displayed on my apache console window only..not display on my android emulator